# Getting Error 500 _____ after setting up basic Python Flask app with cPanel

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, cpanel, namecheap

I'm attempting to host a basic python app on a domain that I purchased through Namecheap and it's being hosted on cPanel. I've followed [this](https://dev.to/lordghostx/how-to-host-flask-applications-on-namecheap-cpanel-299b) tutorial word for word, however I'm receiving this 500 error (image below) and I can't seem to figure it out. Anyone have any suggestions on how to solve this issue? Thank you!

[image: this]

This is my app.py file:

```
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route("/")
def hello():
    return "Hello World!"


@app.route("/<string:name>/")
def say_hello(name):
    return "Hello {name}!"


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

This is my passenger_wsgi.py file:

```
from app import app as application
```

Comment: You need to look at the server logs to find the full stack trace of the error.